# web crawling ,ruby,python,cassandra

Tags: cassandra, web-crawler, nutch, gora

I need to write a script that insert 1-million records  of username or emails by crawling the web, into database.
The script may be any types  like python,ruby,php etc.

Please let me know is it possible ?if possible please provide the information how can I build the script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible may take some time though depending on your machine's performance and your internet connection.
You could use PHP's cURL library to automatically send Web requests and then you could easily parse the data using a library for example :[simplHtmlDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) or using native PHP DOM. But beware of running out of memory, also I highly recommend running the script from shell rather than a web browser. Also consider using multi curl functions, to fasten the process.

This is extreamly easy and fast to implement, although multi-threading would give a huge performance boost in this scenario, so I suggest using one of the other languages you proposed. I know you could do this in Java easily using Apache HttpClient library and manipulate the DOM and extract data using native x-path support, regex or use one of the many third party dom implementations in Java.

I strongly recommend also checking out Java library [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), where it could make your life much easier, but you could maybe take a performance hit for that. A good multi-threading implementation would give a huge performance boost but a bad one could make your program run worse.

Here is some resources for python:
http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html 
http://www.boddie.org.uk/python/HTML.html 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 1):

You should also look at Apache Nutch and Apache Gora which would do what you're looking for.  Nutch does the actual crawling which Gora stores the results in Cassandra, Hive or MySQL

Comment: I know it's late, but this has come along since your question was asked and answered.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a little on crawl side.
you said crawl the web. So here the crawling direction (i.e. after fetching a page, which link to visit next becomes very important). But if you already have a list of webpages (called seed URLs list) with you then you simply need to download them and parse out reqd. data. If you just need to parse email addresses, then regex would be your option. Because html does not have any tag for emails, then htmldom parser wouldnt help you.